# Installing via System.Diagnostics.Process Doesn't Work in 32-Bit/XP?

Tags: c#, command-line, process

I have a c# exe that calls System.Diagnostics.Process to run some commands in cmd.exe that installs a couple installers passively.. I've been testing it on my machine (64-bit win8 and it works just fine, but when I run the exe on a 32-bit version of Windows XP, the program simply skips over the process part. There are no errors thrown, it just ignores them. This is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD.exe", @"/C [command stuff]}");
psi.CreateNoWindow = true;     
psi.UseShellExecute = false;   
System.Diagnostics.Process diag = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
diag.WaitForExit();
diag.Close();
```

What might be the deal here? Again I get no errors, it just ignores it. It's interesing because I can do all of that up there and just run date as the command and it works fine, but it won't run the msi and exe files needed to install. I can't find any information about it working in 64-bit but not 32. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried capturing the output and/or error streams? The error could very well be in the "command stuff" you are not showing us.

Comment: Yea I went through this and no matter what I did I couldn't get it to show me an error, it was the commands that were the problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what my problem was. Before running the .msi to install, I changed directories using the syntax C:/folder/setup.msi. That works fine on my computer, but didn't do anything on the XP one. It turns out it didn't know how to handle the forward slashes. All I had to do was change it to C:\folder\setup.msi and it worked fine. I feel like an idiot, hope this helps someone though lol.